# FxCop doesn't understand null conditional operator

Tags: c#, fxcop, c#-6.0, fxcopcmd

Consider this code:

```
 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
 {
     if (disposed)
         return;

     if (disposing)
     {
         activeFile?.Dispose();
         ...
```

FxCop is identifying this as "CA2213:DisposableFieldsShouldBeDisposed" (for activeFile) because it doesn't seem to understand the `?.` operator.

Is there a known minimum version of FxCop that accepts this?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/291 and https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4830 .

Comment: FxCop in general is obsolete. As the other comments suggest, you should find alternatives.